# Safari, MacOS - Existing MediaStream AudioTrack's readyState is 'ended' after calling getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, typescript, safari, svelte, getusermedia

I have a problem which may be MacOS or WebKit specific, I don't really know. I have googled and searched like crazy, but I can't seem to find a similar case.

Testing on MacOS Ventura 13.0 - had no possibility to test on other Macs.

I am building a small App, that enables the user to choose **multiple** camera inputs, record those and save them as mp4 files. The app gets the microphone input from the chosen cameras as well. In summary, there is an array of MediaStreams that is constructed by calling getUserMedia multiple times.

Outline of the logic can be described like this:

1. User clicks the "Get Devices" button.
2. Call getUserMedia(), specifically just to get the user's permission for looking at audio and video inputs.
3. Call enumareteDevices() - returning all video and audio devices connected to the PC.
4. User clicks "Add" on one of the video inputs.
5. Call getUserMedia(), this time with the chosen device's ID - both the video and audio (from cam's mic)
6. At this point the chosen MediaStream's tracks are all in 'live' readyState - all good.
7. User clicks "Add" on another video input.
8. Call getUserMedia with the chosen device's ID.
9. Immediately console log the previous MediaStream's Audio Tracks - readyState is 'ended'.
10. AudioTracks from the newest stream are all good.

If the user adds another device, the previous AudioTracks gets ended. Essentially, only the newest MediaStream has sound. This also reflects after saving outputs as media files to the disc. The Video Tracks aren't ending - only audio.

I can open the app in Chrome and there it works without problems - all Audio Tracks are 'live' no matter how many streams are present.

#### Code

The app example is in Svelte - don't worry if you don't know it, the way the logic is written is very similar to vanilla JS. The main logic is only 100 lines.

stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-agc1de - if you just want a quick look. Not able to reproduce the problem there, as Stackblitz only works on Chromium browser - where the problem doesn't exist. Main logic is in `src/App.svelte`

[GH repo - App.svelte - main logic](https://github.com/FilipSzutkowski/Multicam-recording-issue/blob/main/src/App.svelte)

You can also clone the repo, run `npm install` and `npm run dev` to test yourself.

#### I have tried

- Disabling autoplay, playsinline attributes while enabling controls on the video element - did not help.
- Disabling the existing audio tracks before calling getUserMedia and enabling them afterwards - did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Safari, sad to say, only handles one active MediaStream at a time. Opening another one closes the existing one. Sigh.

You have to be careful with Safari gUM both on desktops/laptops and iOS /iPadOS, It's a different implementation than Chromium's and Firefox's, and not as good.

Comment: Well that's sad... I just assumed that since the video tracks were fine, I was doing something wrong.